# Construct JSON column from R dataframe columns

Tags: r, json, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

Here is my dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(item = c("Box 1", "Tape", "Roll 1"), Length = c(2, 
 10, 6), Width = c(4,3,3), Height  = c(6, NA, NA), Length_units =
 c("in", "ft", "yd"), option_1 = c("item_length", "item_length",
 "item_length"), option_2 = c("item_width", "item_width",
 "item_width"), option_3 = c("item_height", "color", NA), option_4 =
 c("thickness", NA, NA), width_units = c("in", "in", "in"),
 height_units = c("in", "in", NA), color = c(NA, "clear", NA),
 thickness = c( "200#", NA, NA ))
```

```
    item Length Width Height Length_units    option_1   option_2    option_3  option_4 width_units height_units color thickness
1  Box 1      2     4      6           in item_length item_width item_height thickness          in           in  <NA>      200# 
2   Tape     10     3     NA           ft item_length item_width       color      <NA>          in           in clear      <NA>
3 Roll 1      6     3     NA           yd item_length item_width        <NA>      <NA>          in         <NA>  <NA>      <NA>
```

I want this JSON column below attached to the end of df. Notice the option labels in JSON are according the df option columns and the JSON is dynamic according to the option columns.

```
{"dimensions":"2 in x 4 in x 6 in","thickness":"200#"}
{"dimensions":"10 ft x 3 in","color":"clear"}
{"dimensions":"6 yd x 3 in"}
```

I would greatly appreciate a dplyr solution.

Edited: I want my dataframe to look like this

```
    item Length Width Height Length_units    option_1   option_2    option_3  option_4 width_units height_units color thickness options_json
1  Box 1      2     4      6           in item_length item_width item_height thickness          in           in  <NA>      200# {"dimensions":"2 in x 4 in x 6 in","thickness":"200#"} 
2   Tape     10     3     NA           ft item_length item_width       color      <NA>          in           in clear      <NA> {"dimensions":"10 ft x 3 in","color":"clear"}
3 Roll 1      6     3     NA           yd item_length item_width        <NA>      <NA>          in         <NA>  <NA>      <NA> {"dimensions":"6 yd x 3 in"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may consider to `paste/unite` the columns and then convert to JSON with `toJSON` - as the columns have different case, it may be be better to standardize by converting to lower case (`tolower` - it becomes easier to `get` the corresponding column value from the `_units` column).  Loop `across` the columns (`length:height`), `paste` (`str_c`), the corresponding '_units' column values when the value in the column is non-NA (using `case_when`), then `unite` those column to a single column, `select` the columns of interest and convert to JSON (`toJSON`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyr)
out <- df %>% 
 rename_with(tolower, everything()) %>%
  mutate(across(length:height, 
   ~ case_when(!is.na(.) ~ str_c(.x, get(str_c(cur_column(), "_units")), 
      sep = " ")))) %>%
  unite(dimensions, length, width, height, sep = " x ", na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  select(dimensions, color, thickness) %>%
  toJSON(pretty = TRUE)
```

-output

```
out
[
  {
    "dimensions": "2 in x 4 in x 6 in",
    "thickness": "200#"
  },
  {
    "dimensions": "10 ft x 3 in",
    "color": "clear"
  },
  {
    "dimensions": "6 yd x 3 in"
  }
]
```

---

If we want to create a column, use `mutate` with `rowwise`

```
df <- df %>% 
 rename_with(tolower, everything()) %>%
  mutate(across(length:height, 
   ~ case_when(!is.na(.) ~ str_c(.x, get(str_c(cur_column(), "_units")), 
      sep = " ")))) %>%
  unite(dimensions, length, width, height, sep = " x ", na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  select(dimensions, color, thickness) %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  transmute(options_json = toJSON(cur_data())) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

-output

```
df
  item Length Width Height Length_units    option_1   option_2    option_3  option_4 width_units height_units color thickness
1  Box 1      2     4      6           in item_length item_width item_height thickness          in           in  <NA>      200#
2   Tape     10     3     NA           ft item_length item_width       color      <NA>          in           in clear      <NA>
3 Roll 1      6     3     NA           yd item_length item_width        <NA>      <NA>          in         <NA>  <NA>      <NA>
                                              options_json
1 [{"dimensions":"2 in x 4 in x 6 in","thickness":"200#"}]
2          [{"dimensions":"10 ft x 3 in","color":"clear"}]
3                           [{"dimensions":"6 yd x 3 in"}]
```

---

The `json` format includes the opening/closing square brackets.  We can remove it with `str_remove`

```
df <- df %>% 
 rename_with(tolower, everything()) %>%
  mutate(across(length:height, 
   ~ case_when(!is.na(.) ~ str_c(.x, get(str_c(cur_column(), "_units")), 
      sep = " ")))) %>%
  unite(dimensions, length, width, height, sep = " x ", na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  select(dimensions, color, thickness) %>%
 rowwise %>% 
 transmute(options_json = str_remove_all(toJSON(cur_data()), "\\[|\\]")) %>% 
 ungroup %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

-output

```
  item Length Width Height Length_units    option_1   option_2    option_3  option_4 width_units height_units color thickness
1  Box 1      2     4      6           in item_length item_width item_height thickness          in           in  <NA>      200#
2   Tape     10     3     NA           ft item_length item_width       color      <NA>          in           in clear      <NA>
3 Roll 1      6     3     NA           yd item_length item_width        <NA>      <NA>          in         <NA>  <NA>      <NA>
                                            options_json
1 {"dimensions":"2 in x 4 in x 6 in","thickness":"200#"}
2          {"dimensions":"10 ft x 3 in","color":"clear"}
3                           {"dimensions":"6 yd x 3 in"}
```

---

Or may `unclass` after `rowwise`

```
df <- df %>% 
 rename_with(tolower, everything()) %>%
  mutate(across(length:height, 
   ~ case_when(!is.na(.) ~ str_c(.x, get(str_c(cur_column(), "_units")), 
      sep = " ")))) %>%
  unite(dimensions, length, width, height, sep = " x ", na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  select(dimensions, color, thickness) %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  transmute(options_json = toJSON(keep(unclass(cur_data()), 
     complete.cases), auto_unbox = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

-output

```
> df
  item Length Width Height Length_units    option_1   option_2    option_3  option_4 width_units height_units color thickness
1  Box 1      2     4      6           in item_length item_width item_height thickness          in           in  <NA>      200#
2   Tape     10     3     NA           ft item_length item_width       color      <NA>          in           in clear      <NA>
3 Roll 1      6     3     NA           yd item_length item_width        <NA>      <NA>          in         <NA>  <NA>      <NA>
                                            options_json
1 {"dimensions":"2 in x 4 in x 6 in","thickness":"200#"}
2          {"dimensions":"10 ft x 3 in","color":"clear"}
3                           {"dimensions":"6 yd x 3 in"}

> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ item        : chr  "Box 1" "Tape" "Roll 1"
 $ Length      : num  2 10 6
 $ Width       : num  4 3 3
 $ Height      : num  6 NA NA
 $ Length_units: chr  "in" "ft" "yd"
 $ option_1    : chr  "item_length" "item_length" "item_length"
 $ option_2    : chr  "item_width" "item_width" "item_width"
 $ option_3    : chr  "item_height" "color" NA
 $ option_4    : chr  "thickness" NA NA
 $ width_units : chr  "in" "in" "in"
 $ height_units: chr  "in" "in" NA
 $ color       : chr  NA "clear" NA
 $ thickness   : chr  "200#" NA NA
 $ options_json: 'json' chr  "{\"dimensions\":\"2 in x 4 in x 6 in\",\"thickness\":\"200#\"}" "{\"dimensions\":\"10 ft x 3 in\",\"color\":\"clear\"}" "{\"dimensions\":\"6 yd x 3 in\"}"
```